# Erlang: How to limit the memory assigned to a process

Tags: erlang, heap-memory, stack-memory, memory-limit

What I'm asking is if it's possible to limit memory (heap or stack) assigned to a specific process, so that this process can't exceed it.
Maybe something like "process_flag(min_heap_size, MinHeapSize)", but for the maximum heap.

Comment: I don't think it is possible now.

Answer (score 6):

You could put together some kind of process tracking gen_server that periodically checks assigned processes for memory footprint and kills them if it exceeds a certain amount.

Using a combination of `process_info(Pid, memory).` and `exit(Pid, Reason)` calls, this should be quite manageable.

Comment: That's what I did :-) I made a check every 2 seconds, but in 2 seconds everything can happen!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `spawn_opt` with `max_heap_size`