# How to limit process memory in Erlang

Tags: memory-management, erlang

I would like to know how I can limit the maximum memory (heap) a process can use to allocate objects.
I looked into spawn_opt with max_heap_size as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699559/erlang-how-to-limit-the-memory-assigned-to-a-process) but I keep getting a badarg error. Is this even possible now? I want to avoid using a gen server to kill the process when heapsize goes over a limit.

```
-module(maxMemCheck).
-export([fib/1,printfib/1]).
-export([main/0]).

printfib(N) -> 
   Res = maxMemCheck:fib(N),
   io:fwrite("~w ~w~n", [N, Res]).

fib(0) -> 0 ; 
fib(1) -> 1 ; 
fib(N) when N > 0 -> fib(N-1) + fib(N-2) .

main () ->
    spawn_opt(maxMemCheck,printfib,[10],[{max_heap_size,#{size => 300, kill => true, error_logger => true}}]).
```

This results in the error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{erlang,spawn_opt,[maxMemCheck,fib,"\n",[{max_heap_size,#{error_logger=>true,kill=>true,size=>300}}]],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct, maybe you are using an "old" erlang version. This syntax uses a map variable which was introduced in OTP18 or 19.

Comment: I am using OTP 18. It worked when I updated to the latest version of OTP (20.3). Thanks!